# Array not updating itself correctly. Strange behavior

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to make a function that takes live market tick data from MT5 and feeds it into a custom pyqtgraph candlestick chart.
I've set up the function so that it keeps rewriting the new data to the same row until the bar number is updated, so there is intra-candle ticks being generated on the graph without generating new overlapping bars every time new data comes in before the next candle needs to be generated on the timer.

However I am gettingh very strange behavior when updating the array that I'm using to generate the data.

When I call

```
chart_array[b , 2]
```

I get the correct value for that slot, however when I call the entire array

```
chart_array[:b]
```

It shows something completely different, and it repeats the same values instead of updating the row with new ones.

I spent all day yesterday working into the early hours of the morning trying to figure out why the array isn't updating properly. I am totally baffled.

I currently have it set to update "b" every 6 seconds through current_minutes(), "b" updates the new row and the data is supposed to continuously replace itself on the same row until the next row is generated by "b".
However the array just spams the same numbers even though the ticks and chart_array[b , 2] have technically been updated to new numbers if you call print(chart_array[b , 2]) directly. It's as if two arrays have been generated.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import threading
import queue
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


# ----------------    
if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()

# attempt to enable the display of the GBPUSD in MarketWatch
selected = mt5.symbol_select("EURUSD", True)
if not selected:
    print("Failed to select EURUSD")
    mt5.shutdown()
    quit()

b = 0


        
def update_chart( *args):
    global b
    current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")
    last_tick = 0
    chart_array = np.zeros((100000, 3), dtype=float)


    while True:

        current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")

        if last_tick != current_tick:
            last_tick = current_tick

            # The output = bar, previous tick value, current tick value
            chart_array[b , 0], chart_array[b , 1], chart_array[b , 2] = b, chart_array[b  - 1, 2], current_tick[1]
            
            print(" tick number is " + str(chart_array[b , 2]))
            
            tickq.put(chart_array[:b])
            i = tickq.get()
            
            print("array is \n"+ str(i))
            tickq.task_done()

        else:
            pass
            
def current_minutes():
    """time interval between bar update"""
    global b
    minutes = 0.1
    nanoseconds = minutes * 6e+10
    start = time.time_ns()
    time.perf_counter_ns()
    elapsed = 0
    
    while elapsed < nanoseconds:
        elapsed = time.time_ns() - start
        
    b +=1
    print("sending")
    current_minutes()


tickq = queue.Queue()
t4 = threading.Thread(target=current_minutes, args=())
t4.start()

t3 = threading.Thread(target=update_chart, args=())
t3.start()
```

Here is the output of the array when i is called.
Scroll down if you want to see the array growing.

```
 tick number is 0.99688
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99691
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99688
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99692
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99691
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99688
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[]
 tick number is 0.99687
array is 
[]
sending
 tick number is 0.99688
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99684
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99683
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99684
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99684
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99683
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99682
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99683
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99684
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99687
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99687
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [7.      0.99686 0.99687]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [7.      0.99686 0.99687]]
sending
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [7.      0.99686 0.99687]
 [8.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [7.      0.99686 0.99687]
 [8.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99687
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.99687]
 [1.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [2.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [3.      0.99686 0.99685]
 [4.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [5.      0.99685 0.99685]
 [6.      0.99685 0.99686]
 [7.      0.99686 0.99687]
 [8.      0.99687 0.99685]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]]
sending
sending
sending
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]]
sending
sending
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99685
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99686
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]]
 tick number is 0.99689
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]]
sending
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[ 0.       0.       0.99687]
 [ 1.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 2.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 3.       0.99686  0.99685]
 [ 4.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 5.       0.99685  0.99685]
 [ 6.       0.99685  0.99686]
 [ 7.       0.99686  0.99687]
 [ 8.       0.99687  0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [10.       0.       0.99687]
 [11.       0.99687  0.99686]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [14.       0.       0.99685]
 [ 0.       0.       0.     ]
 [16.       0.       0.99686]
 [17.       0.99686  0.99689]]
```

The values displayed by "tick number is" should appear in the right-most row and column of the updated array, however it spams the same values or incorrect values.

Can anyone explain to me why the array is not updating properly?
If I call the specific slots in the array I get the correct values but if I call the entire array the values are all wrong. This is way over my head.
Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT
I've tried passing "b" through queue.Queue and using time.sleep as suggested but it didn't seem to help much. Lots of random zero values in chart_array[b , 0] and chart_array[b , 2] is still not being updated properly.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import threading
import queue
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


# ----------------    
if not mt5.initialize():
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()

# attempt to enable the display of the GBPUSD in MarketWatch
selected = mt5.symbol_select("EURUSD", True)
if not selected:
    print("Failed to select EURUSD")
    mt5.shutdown()
    quit()

b = 0


        
def update_chart( *args):
    global b
    current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")
    last_tick = 0
    chart_array = np.zeros((100000, 3), dtype=float)


    while True:
        b = bq.get()
        current_tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick("EURUSD")

        if last_tick != current_tick:
            last_tick = current_tick


            chart_array[b , 0], chart_array[b , 1], chart_array[b , 2] = b, chart_array[b  - 1, 2], current_tick[1]
            
            print(" tick number is " + str(chart_array[b , 2]))
            
            tickq.put(chart_array[:b])
            i = tickq.get()
            
            print("array is \n"+ str(i))
            tickq.task_done()
            bq.task_done()

        else:
            pass
            
def current_minutes():
    global b

    time.sleep(6)
    b += 1
    bq.put(b)
    print("sending")
    current_minutes()

bq = queue.Queue()
tickq = queue.Queue()
t4 = threading.Thread(target=current_minutes, args=())
t4.start()

t3 = threading.Thread(target=update_chart, args=())
t3.start()
```

---

```
sending tick number is 0.99693

array is 
[[0. 0. 0.]]
 tick number is 0.99695 tick number is 0.99695
array is 
[[0. 0. 0.]]

array is 
[[0. 0. 0.]]
 tick number is 0.99694
array is 
[[0. 0. 0.]]
 tick number is 0.99694
array is 
[[0. 0. 0.]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99695 tick number is 0.99695
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]
 tick number is 0.99696 tick number is 0.99696
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]
 tick number is 0.99697 tick number is 0.99697
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]]
sending
 tick number is 0.99696 tick number is 0.99696
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]]
sending
sending
sending
 tick number is 0.9969 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.9969
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99696 tick number is 0.99696
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99697 tick number is 0.99697
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99696 tick number is 0.99696
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]

array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
 tick number is 0.99697 tick number is 0.99697
array is 
[[0.      0.      0.     ]
 [1.      0.      0.99694]
 [2.      0.99694 0.99697]
 [3.      0.99697 0.99696]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]
 [0.      0.      0.     ]]
```

If I remove 'global b' from update_chart() in the above example it corrupts the while loop and the array only updates once every 6 seconds instead of when mt5 feeds in data.

For starters "b" has nothing to do with my main issue. I don't think the people that gave me suggestions spent time to read the issue.
The issue is with chart_array[b , 2] not updating. "b" only affects chart_array[b , 0] and is not my concern right now.

Comment: Your `current_minutes` loop is consuming 100% of a CPU.  You absolutely need to add `time.sleep(1)` in there.

Comment: `b` is always 0.  `chart_array[:b]` will always be an empty array.  Were you trying to look at the whole row?  Did you mean `chart_array[b,:]`?  Or, equivalently, `chart_array[b]`?

Comment: current_minutes doesn't increase the CPU by any noticeable degree and functions properly, I need extreme accuracy on the timer so a delay is unwanted.
As you can see by the output I posted above the array is not empty. Scroll down a bit.
I need chart_array[:b] because expanding arrays is too slow so I start off with a large array and only output the rows between 0 and the current updated row.

Comment: @thatoneguy Looks like you're sharing a global variable between threads, without any protection ? That's one way of getting exactly the issues you're seein. Since you already use a Queue, communicate everything through that queue, including `b`. You also really, really want to take the advice others have given you to not burn CPU and lock up the entire python interperter with your while loop in `current_minutes()`. You can sleep for much less than 1 second if that's your main concern, and you can work out latency/performance issues with using sleep after you got it working

Comment: I guarantee you chat `current_minutes` is chewing up your CPU.  Remember that the GIL means only one thread at a time can be executing Python code.  While you're in that loop, your other thread is blocked.  Note after the 7th row that you went for 6 seconds without doing any fetches of the tick value.  You had two "sendings" without any updates.  Also note that your recursive call to `current_minutes` is going to grow your stack until you overflow it.  That should be in a loop.

Comment: And if you think you are getting sub-millisecond accuracy on your timing, you do not understand either threading or Python.  At the very least, do `time.sleep(0.1)` in that loop, but you could replace that with `time.sleep(6)` and do just as well.

Comment: @ nos I'm only using global in this example the full script only uses threads and function calls. I haven't tried passing b. through queue however it does work as is, I'll try it and see what happens. As for the sleep, I've seen on other threads that time.sleep is not very accurate down to the ms/ns.  How else am I supposed to do this? As of now I don't see any performance degradation in the task manager or in the charts GUI.

Comment: @ Tim Roberts the reason there is inconsistency in the updates is simply that there are periods where no data is being fed in. It is entirely random. Still, I'll try as you say, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I tried the advice but was unable to succeed. Please review my updated post.

Comment: Then I'm no longer sure what the problem is.  Are you objecting to the 0 values in there?

Comment: The primary issue is that chart_array[b , 2] does not get updated when data is received. chart_array[b , 2] should be replaced every time tick data is received by MT5 by the data labeled as "tick number is". Please review my original question closer.  "b" only updates chart_array[b , 0]  and is not the primary issue. Although the  random zero values in  chart_array[b , 0]  are a concern they are not the main concern.